# How to filter strings without IF statements c#

Tags: c#

The code below does what I want except for the fact it is too hard coded and will display construction materials with the value 0. Right now it might display

Wood : 100%, Masonry: 0%, Concrete: 0%, Steel: 0%, Light Metal: 0%, Mobile Home: 0%, Other: 0%, Unknown: 0%

I would like it to display in that case

Wood: 100%

I am an extreme amatuer and the only way I know how to do this is with 10000 IF statements but there must be a more elegant way. the function convertFIRE is a mapping to these major construction 'buckets'

```
for (int row = firstrow + 1; row <= sheet5.LastRowNum; row++)
{
    convertFIRE(sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).ToString());

    if (constructioncode == "Wood")
    {
        wood = wood + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Masonry")
    {
        masonry = masonry + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Concrete")
    {
        concrete = concrete + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Steel")
    {
        steel = steel + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Light Metal")
    {
        lghtmetal = lghtmetal + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Mobile Home")
    {
        mobilehome = mobilehome + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Other")
    {
        other = other + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }
    else if (constructioncode == "Unknown")
    {
        unknowncode = unknowncode + sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    }

}
constructiontext = "Wood: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", wood) + ", " + "Masonry: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", masonry) + ", " + "Concrete: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", concrete) + ", "
    + "Steel: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", steel) + ", " + "Light Metal: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", lghtmetal) + ", " + "Mobile Home: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", mobilehome) + ", " + "Other: " + String.Format("{0:P1}.", other) + ", " + "Unknown: " + String.Format("{0:P1}", unknowncode);
```

Comment: I think you should read http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/poor-mans-polymorphism-or-whats-so-wrong-about-if-then-else

Comment: Should probably go to Review.StackExchange.com, not?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm not so sure if "refactor this code" would be on-topic on [CodeReview.SE] now, but you are right - in the past exactly the same question was ok - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46530/how-to-refactor-multiple-if-statements

Comment: I'd recommend to learn about existence of search engines. They are quite old and may not be in frequent use nowdays :), but try it - Google, Yahoo, Bing https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+refactor+multiple+if (and many more) frequently will give you answer (also you'll miss on reputation points on SO if you ask before searching...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have several variables to track numbers based on a key string.  Rather than several variables, you could use a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> percentages = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
for (int row = firstrow + 1; row <= sheet5.LastRowNum; row++)
{
    convertFIRE(sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).ToString());
    string key = constructioncode;
    decimal value = sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue;
    if(percentages.ContainsKey(key);  // does the key already exist?
        percentages[key] += value;    // add to the value
    else                              // else
        percentages[key] = value;     // add the key and value to the dictionary
```

You can then loop through the key-value pairs and only output the key and value if the value is present and/or greater then 0.

Comment: This combined with below works great, I have learned a lot today and have many other places I could implement similar!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `Dictionary<string, int>` with all your values where the `string`-Key will be your `"Steel"` and so on.
You then can do something like this:

```
if (dic.ContainsKey(constructioncode)) {
  dic[constructioncode] += sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue
} else {
  //Maybe add as new key???
  dic.Add(constructioncode, sheet5.GetRow(row).GetCell(10).NumericCellValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since neither of the other answers describe how to turn a Dictionary to the String you want, here's that part:

```
constructiontext = string.Join(", ", dictionary.Where(kv => kv.Value != 0).Select(kv => kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value + "%").ToArray());
```

Also, your code is more readable if you use camelCase (using a capital letter when you start a new subword in a variable name). It's the generally accepted standard when writing C# code, which means that anyone who has to maintain your code afterwards can start doing so right away. So instead of `constructioncode`, write `constructionCode`. Instead of `constructiontext`, write `constructionText`. instead of `mobilehome`, write `mobileHome`, etc.